# What are the white specks on this lens barrel?

Tags: lens, used-equipment, fungus

Recently I got some used lenses most of which have some white specks on the barrel next to the focus and aperture rings. These lenses came from different sources and weren't stored in a same place. Maybe it's an amateur question, but I've never seen this before.  I'm worried about mold or fungus.

Is it because of humid weather, or is it normal?

[image]

Comment: You'd need to check with a microscope, but most likely it's paint or anodizing worn off.

Comment: It's a little bit of stray cocaine powder from the drug smuggler who had this lens before you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are scratches and dings due to rough handling. They are probably just cosmetic defects. Likely the lens performance will be OK.

These lens barrels are aluminum and the black is anodizing, a chemical treatment. Some areas are black enamel. Again, what you see is rough handling but not necessarily an indication that mold or mildew has infected the optics.

Answer (score 1):

Could be tissue paper dust from cleaning the lens with soft tissue.